# Something is wrong with my Mac's network connectivity; how can I debug this?

Tags: networking, google-chrome, mac, vpn

A couple months ago I installed Tunnelblick on my Mac OS Sierra 10.12 system, for the purposes of connecting to a university VPN. After connecting to the VPN, I found that many websites that I use would break; for example, Facebook would every now and then load only half the page. I also can't watch videos on Facebook either, as the video would just break after a short period of time. Downloading / uploading files to and from Facebook would also not work, and I would receive a network error.

This doesn't just apply for Facebook - across many of the websites I visit, sporadically I get a "Network error" message in Google Chrome, saying that "my connection has changed".

The VPN itself was still working; I could access intranet sites on the VPN itself, so the VPN connection was successful.

After I had no more use for the VPN, I uninstalled Tunnelblick using the given uninstaller file, thinking it would fix my network connection, but this problem has persisted since then. At first I thought it was my ISP's problem, but I recently bought a new Macbook Air, and all websites, all downloading, all uploading; it all works fine.

I am using the same Google Chrome profile across both devices, with the same extensions, so I don't think the issue is in Google Chrome.

Is there any debugging / troubleshooting I can do to possibly resolve this issue?

This is my "Proxies" section under the "Network" tab of System Preferences:

[image: Proxy config]

All the checkboxes are unchecked and My DNS settings are completely empty, with only the default configuration options listed. If there is anything else I can do to debug this, please let me know and I would be happy to add more information into here.

Comment: Check to see if you have a proxy configured.

Comment: @Spiff Hmm, that might've been it. I've included my proxy screen above.

Comment: How about the other tabs, like DNS

Comment: @JohnDoe I don't have any special DNS settings, either - please refer to my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You mention the problem is sporadic, which is not how I have experienced post-VPN problems so I'll focus on the error.  The network changed error led me to lookup ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED.  [This thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/V_wyBDxV9Yk) from the google products forum suggests the following has helped some people.  (Copied with minor edits):

1. Quit Google Chrome completely.
2. Open the directory `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/` in Finder.**
3. Rename the folder `Default` to something else, like `Backup Default`.
4. Restart Chrome

** To open in Finder, one method:

1. Open Finder
2. Click the `Go` menu at the top of the screen.
3. Select the menu entry `Go to Folder`
4. Type or paste `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/`
5. Click the `Go` button.